# When converting an R package documentation from .Rd to PDF, text in table (\tabular) does not break line.

Tags: r, pdf

In my package [squid](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/squid/), I have created a table in the documentation with the `\tabular` tag. When I convert the .Rd file documentation to a pdf file, the text inside each row of that table does not break lines anymore and goes outside the page limits ([link to the pdf file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/squid/squid.pdf), Table in page 6).

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe use itemize instead of a table?

Comment: Have you used `\cr` to break the line?

Comment: @J_F Yes I did use \cr to break the line between the table rows. The problem is to break line inside a cell.

Comment: @Thomas, yes I can use itemize instead but I prefer the table formatting. I have a lot of information to display and a table is clearer.

Comment: You could try the LaTeX-style `p{1in}` alignment, but it's not documented so it may not work.

Comment: @Thomas. No the R documentation format does not support latex syntaxe.